# what is %username% in FTP

Tags: batch, ftp, cmd.exe

I just made a script to upload important files, but there are more then 1 user on my computer and I want it to upload the user that is using the program.. so like in cmd I tried to do something like this

upload.bat here

```
  @echo off
  ftp -s:%~dp0Upload.ftp
  pause
```

upload.ftp here

```
   open (ftp server name)
   (ftp server user-name)
   (ftp server password)
   prompt
   bin
   mput c:\user\%USERNAME%\importantfiles
   bye
```

But this failed me, so now I am asking you..

**How do I set a directory to the user-name of the user of the program?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ftp` command doesn't seem to support [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows) at all; consider creating the FTP script on the fly. Here's an example script mostly borrowed from [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FtpBatchUsingVariables):

```
;@echo off
;(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~f0") do call echo.%%A)>"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
;ftp -i -s:"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
;goto:EOF

open example.com
username
password
!:--- FTP commands below here ---
prompt
bin
mput %userprofile%\importantfiles
```

**Note** Use `%userprofile%` rather then building the path yourself, because there are different things that can go wrong:

- You have typos, e.g. `C:\User` rather than `C:\Users`.
- The folder name doesn't match the user account name.
- Windows is not installed in the `C:` drive/partition.

### How it works

> This batch executed the FTP script embedded within the batch. All variables in the FTP script will be resolved.
>
> The [FOR](http://www.dostips.com/DosCommandIndex.htm#FOR) loop extracts the FTP script into a temporary file. It the [ECHO](http://www.dostips.com/DosCommandIndex.htm#ECHO) command is being [CALL](http://www.dostips.com/DosCommandIndex.htm#CALL)ed for each line in order to resolve the variables.
>
> Variables can be used within the FTP script the same way as in a batch script, including any [string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) and command line arguments like `%1` `%2` `%~n0` `%*` and so on.
>
> All batch lines start with semicolon so that they will be ignored by the [FOR](http://www.dostips.com/DosCommandIndex.htm#FOR) loop. Semicolon is the default end-of-line (EOL) character used by the [FOR](http://www.dostips.com/DosCommandIndex.htm#FOR) command.
>
> <sub>Source: [FTP - Resolving Environment Variables](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FtpBatchUsingVariables)</sub>

### References

- [Is it possible to pass a variable into a Windows FTP script file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170627/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-variable-into-a-windows-ftp-script-file)
- [FTP - Resolving Environment Variables](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FtpBatchUsingVariables)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use all upercase `%USERNAME%`.

Comment: Did not work still just said "C:\user\%USERNAME%\importantfiles" file not found

Comment: If you are using Windows 7 or 8, the main folder on C is Users and not User

Comment: Environment variables are not case-sensitive. Regardless, the problem is that environment variables aren't resolved in the OP usage case.